# Saving an item back to Sitecore using GlassMapper

Tags: c#, sitecore, glass-mapper

I have a object that was created using GlassMapper without doing a verbose property-by-property assignment?

```
information.Fields["field1"].Value = obj.Value
...
```

I was using [this](http://learnsitecore.cmsuniverse.net/Developers/Articles/2009/06/ProgramaticallyItems2.aspx) as a reference and it is helpful, but I want to use GlassMapper to save the items back. I tried using the following code block to use my GlassMapper object but I reach an exception that I explain below:

```
            Debug.Assert(informationItem != null, "informationItem != null");
            informationItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
            informationItem.GlassRead(model); //Could not find item to save value AbstractPropertyConfiguration Property: Position
            informationItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

In my information model I declare CandidatePosition as such :

`public virtual CandidatePosition Position { get; set; }`

and the CandidatePosition is defined as such:

```
[SitecoreType]
public class CandidatePosition : BaseItem
{
    [SitecoreField]
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
}
```

So the Title field should map to the Title field in the Sitecore item, but I think it is having trouble mapping it? I can confirm that the underlying object is not null and the Title field does have a value. Is there some attribute I'm missing that I need to apply or maybe I'm not following some convention?

I *could* go manual and just do it property by property but I feel it might not be necessary.

Comment: The Glass website has a tutorial on how to save items: http://glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial11

Comment: Seems like you need `informationItem.GlassRead(model.Position);` since Position is the item you are trying to save back.